# Convert a simple unordered list into a nested list depending on the content of its list items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been looking for a solution that can help me to convert a single level html list into a multi level one.

**The HTML Code looks like this before the conversion:**

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Main</a></li>
    <li><a>_Sub Menu</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-1</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-2</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**The desired output after the conversion is:**

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Main</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Sub Menu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Sub Sub Menu-1</a></li>
                    <li><a>Sub Sub Menu-2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Sub Sub Menu-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Here is the jQuery plugin code I already have:** (it does the job, but i need it in plain Javascript)

```js
! function(a) {
  a.fn.menuMaker = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $t = a(this),
        b = $t.find('.LinkList ul > li').children('a'),
        c = b.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        var d = b.eq(i),
          h = d.text();
        if (h.charAt(0) !== '_') {
          var e = b.eq(i + 1),
            j = e.text();
          if (j.charAt(0) === '_') {
            var m = d.parent();
            m.append('<ul class="sub-menu m-sub"/>');
          }
        }
        if (h.charAt(0) === '_') {
          d.text(h.replace('_', ''));
          d.parent().appendTo(m.children('.sub-menu'));
        }
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        var f = b.eq(i),
          k = f.text();
        if (k.charAt(0) !== '_') {
          var g = b.eq(i + 1),
            l = g.text();
          if (l.charAt(0) === '_') {
            var n = f.parent();
            n.append('<ul class="sub-menu2 m-sub"/>');
          }
        }
        if (k.charAt(0) === '_') {
          f.text(k.replace('_', ''));
          f.parent().appendTo(n.children('.sub-menu2'));
        }
      }
      $t.find('.LinkList ul li ul').parent('li').addClass('has-sub');
    });
  }
}(jQuery);
```

**Here is the equivalent JavaScript code I wrote, but it's not working**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var b = document.querySelectorAll("#menu li a"),
    c = b.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    var d = b[i],
      h = d.innerText;
    if (h.charAt(0) !== "_") {
      var e = b[i + 1],
        j = e.innerText;
      if (j.charAt(0) === "_") {
        var m = d.parentNode;
        var subMenu = document.createElement("ul");
        subMenu.className = "sub-menu";
        subMenu.appendChild(m);
        console.log(m.querySelector(".sub-menu"));
      }
    }
    if (h.charAt(0) === "_") {
      d.innerText = h.replace("_", "");
      var name = document.createElement("div");
      d.appendChild(name);
    }
  }
});
```

How can i convert the list with plain vanilla Javascript?

Comment: Can it have multiple main and sub menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by using `appendChild()` and `document.createElement()`.

If you only have one main menu item and one sub menu item, you could first loop through the list elements and get the `textContent`:

```js
const menu_items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

for (i = 0; i < menu_items.length; i++) {
  const link_content = menu_items[i].textContent;
```

If you want to remove the underscores, you can do this with `replaceAll()`;

```js
menu_items[i].querySelector('a').textContent = link_content.replaceAll('_', '');
```

Then you could check the text content (stored before in the var `link_content`) with `charAt()` if at position 0 and 1 are underscores and do in the corresponding cases the nesting of the elements.

If there is no underscore at the beginning, it must be the main menu item, else if there is no underscore at the second position, it must be the sub menu item and in the remaining case it must be a sub sub menu item.

Besause you need additional `<ul>` elements for the nested sub menu layers you could use a simple function, where you create such an element, append it to the actual menu item and return that `<ul>` element for appending the other elements later:

```js
function create_sub_menu(elem) {
  const sub_list = document.createElement('UL');
  elem.appendChild(sub_list);
  return sub_list;
}
```

If the actual menu item is a main menu item, you just need to store the returned `<ul>` element in a var for appending the other elements later:

```js
if (link_content.charAt(0) !== '_') {
  main_menu = create_sub_menu(menu_items[i]);
}
```

If it's a sub menu item, you also need to store the returned element in a var and additionally you need to append it to the main menu `<ul>` element:

```js
else if (link_content.charAt(1) !== '_') {
  sub_menu = create_sub_menu(menu_items[i]);;
    
  main_menu.appendChild(menu_items[i]);
}
```

And last, if it's a sub sub menu item, you just need to append it to the sub menu `<ul>` element:

```js
else {
  sub_menu.appendChild(menu_items[i]);
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
const menu_items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
let main_menu;
let sub_menu;

function create_sub_menu(elem) {
  const sub_list = document.createElement('UL');
  elem.appendChild(sub_list);
  return sub_list;
}

for (i = 0; i < menu_items.length; i++) {
  const link_content = menu_items[i].textContent;
  menu_items[i].querySelector('a').textContent = link_content.replaceAll('_', '');
  
  if (link_content.charAt(0) !== '_') {
    main_menu = create_sub_menu(menu_items[i]);
  }
  else if (link_content.charAt(1) !== '_') {
    sub_menu = create_sub_menu(menu_items[i]);
    
    main_menu.appendChild(menu_items[i]);
  }
  else {
    sub_menu.appendChild(menu_items[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Main</a></li>
    <li><a>_Sub Menu</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-1</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-2</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

This also works for multiple main and sub menu items. But you should check the next menu item (if there is one) for underscores with an additional `if` statement to prevent creating unnecessary `<ul>` elements:

```js
//for a main menu item
if (menu_items[i + 1] && menu_items[i + 1].textContent.charAt(0) === '_') {
  main_menu = create_sub_menu(menu_items[i]);
}
```

```js
//for a sub menu item
if (menu_items[i + 1] && menu_items[i + 1].textContent.charAt(1) === '_') {
  sub_menu = create_sub_menu(menu_items[i]);
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
const menu_items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
let main_menu;
let sub_menu;

function create_sub_menu(elem) {
  const sub_list = document.createElement('UL');
  elem.appendChild(sub_list);
  return sub_list;
}

for (i = 0; i < menu_items.length; i++) {
  const link_content = menu_items[i].textContent;
  menu_items[i].querySelector('a').textContent = link_content.replaceAll('_', '');
  
  if (link_content.charAt(0) !== '_') {
    if (menu_items[i + 1] && menu_items[i + 1].textContent.charAt(0) === '_') {
      main_menu = create_sub_menu(menu_items[i]);
    }
  }
  else if (link_content.charAt(1) !== '_') {
    if (menu_items[i + 1] && menu_items[i + 1].textContent.charAt(1) === '_') {
      sub_menu = create_sub_menu(menu_items[i]);
    }
    
    main_menu.appendChild(menu_items[i]);
  }
  else {
    sub_menu.appendChild(menu_items[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Main Menu-1</a></li>
    <li><a>_Sub Menu-1</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-1</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-2</a></li>
    <li><a>__Sub Sub Menu-3</a></li>
    <li><a>_Sub Menu-2</a></li>
    <li><a>_Sub Menu-3</a></li>
    <li><a>Main Menu-2</a></li>
    <li><a>Main Menu-3</a></li>
    <li><a>_Sub Menu-1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It will be appreciated if underscore form text content is removed. It was just used as a short code

Comment: Also all the list items are wrapped in new UL element, but It should be like to add all list items in one UL for the fist submenu.

Comment: Oh i forget that the sub menu items get their own UL - i will fix this today (i think the first UL must be added in the first main menu IF). To replace the underscores use ``strreplace()`` or something like that - just google it...

Comment: There is a js function called `replace` but it's not working for me. 

Comment: There is also a function ``replaceAll()``...

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer and also used ``replaceAll()``. If that answers your question,  you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Marking your answer as accepted but at this line `menu_items[i + 1].textContent` it says Cannot read properties of undefined.

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot to check if there is a next menu item. Fixed it now...